# How to display the details of NSArray in DetailView using TableViewController?

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, nsarray, uitableview

i fetch data from server and populate VableView according to income data array. I want to my app display the details of the string in a new view when the user clicks on the cell. I've populated the TableView and connected a new view and can push new view by clicking the cell, but i have no idea about how to connect all elements of array with the second view.

```
//the result is JSON data i bring from a url
    NSMutableArray *messageContentArray= [[result objectForKey:@"message"] valueForKey:@"message"];

                NSUserDefaults *savedContec=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                [savedContec setObject:messageContentArray forKey:@"messageArray"];
```

This is my code of parsing the data and saving it and:

```
 NSArray *someThing=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"messageArray"];

    cell.textLabel.text= [someThing objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    

  //  NSString *st= [someThing substringToIndex:10];
  // i will show first 10 charakters from the message as the cell.textlabe.tex but haven't
  // prepared that part.. What i want is, when i click a cell, in the second view display 
  // all the text for that element of array
```

this is how i populate the tableview cells. As i explained in the code, when i click a cell, i want to display  all the text for that element of array in the second view.

NOTE: I have prapared views and connections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wether u have done any sample app, how to display the data onto views...

check the below sample

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1797/how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-tutorial-part-1

there are 3 parts in this tutorial, go through it, u will come to know how to use it in ur app.

Comment: I took a fast look at the link it looks very good, especially for newbies(like me:) Thanks

Comment: if it solved your issue, accept the answer. so that ques will be closed.